# IIS GUI Interface to Edit Application Host File for a Specific Website, Not the Default App

Tags: configuration, iis-7.5

I have noticed that there used to be an Administration Pack V1 for IIS to make non-default app modifications to the applicationHost.config, but it does not seem to be available for download anymore. ["Editing Collections with Configuration Editor"](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/editing-collections-with-configuration-editor). Not sure if this tool been replaced for another one. I installed "Application Initialization 1.0 for IIS 7.5". I can get to the to the defaultapppool configuration area that I am looking for in the IIS Manager. But, I cannot seem to make edits through the GUI interface required in this tutorial ["Auto-Start ASP.NET Applications (VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 Series)"](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series).

Specifically from the tutorial, I would like to make edits/adds to the following sections and attributes in the applicationHost.config using a GUI:

```
<applicationPools>
    <add name="MyAppWorkerProcess" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning" />
</applicationPools>

<sites>
     <site name="MySite" id="1">
          <application path="/" serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" serviceAutoStartProvider="PreWarmMyCache" />
     </site>
</sites>

<serviceAutoStartProviders>
     <add name="PreWarmMyCache" type="PreWarmCache, MyAssembly" />
</serviceAutoStartProviders>
```

Answer (score 2):

From your first link I can see that they are editing the config for the whole server, so I see why you're confused.  To answer your question simply, yes you can edit the config for a specific app and not the whole site by going to **IIS Manager > Expand Server Name > Expand Site > Click on your app underneath your site > in the main column (middle) double click on Configuration Editor.**

You will need to make sure you select the right Section once you're on the app config editor too.  See my screenshot below for an example of the different sections each editor is capable of editing.

[image]

Comment: Where in that dropdown can I see applicationPools to make the following changes:<applicationPools><add name="MyAppWorkerProcess" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning" /></applicationPools>

Comment: Also, thank for your response, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/speeding-up-your-application-with-the-iis-auto-start-feature/) website:

You want to find this screen in IIS Mananger:

[image: IIS Manager]

Select Application Pools, then select your app, click advance settings and you can update the startMode to AlwaysRunning or adjust other settings as you please.

[image]